# Changing Trigger notification settings programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-apps-script-editor

I am using App Script trigger for doing some operation every N minutes.

The problem is every day it will send a **Summary of failures** email.
I would like to know whether there is any way to turn off this summary of failures email programmatically, following is the code I am using for creating the trigger.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").timeBased().everyMinutes(N).create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to 'programmatically' turn off the failure emails.

Go to the Apps Script Editor > Current Project Triggers and click the notifications link. Delete the notification to stop receiving the summaries.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can turn off the failure emails by deleting the trigger. No trigger -> No emails. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deleteTrigger(Trigger)

```js
function clearAllTriggers() {
  // Deletes all triggers in the current project.
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('All triggers have been removed.');
}
```